# VueJS v-bind not working with kebab-case

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a task list with Vue.JS (like everyone) and I've managed to add a task, show the tasks and even to delete the tasks. After that I was working on checking tasks and give them a class for success.

So I thought, if I have a data like `class` set to false, and use this line of code:

```
<div v-for="(task, index) in tasks" class="panel panel-default" :class="{panel-success: task.class}" :key="task">
```

I could set the `class` to `true` with a click event and give the particular class of `panel-success` (from bootstrap).

When I was doing that, I came up to the following problem:

> avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "class" in expression :class="{panel-success: task.class}"

The problem was, the kebab case syntax of `panel-success`. When I changed the name `to panelsuccess` it was working. Why is kebab case not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value for `:class` is a Javascript object, and in Javascript objects a kebab-case identifier is not valid, that's why you're having that error. For it to work, simply wrap your kebab-case identifier around single quotes:

```
:class="{'panel-success': task.class}"
```